# Load testing a model glider wing

Tags: wing, model-aircraft

I wish to load test a model glider wing.

The standard static load test methodology using sandbags on the upturned wing would be difficult as the chord of the wing is small - it will be difficult to securely attach the loads required.

Are there any other methods commonly in use to do this kind of test that might be easier?

Comment: How much of a chord and span do you have? I have used discrete loads for this in the past (partially filled water bottled suspended at specific span sections).

Answer (score 1):

You can still use some small bags with flour or other soft material inside.

For the wing load test, the bending moment is more critical than the torsion. Therefore, the flour-bags could work fine.

If you want to add torsion and a more precise loading, you can build some sectional fixtures that transfer point loads to the wing.

Comment: Thank you. The loads we want to test with are quite high - and there is limited space on the wing. I'm planning to make up some sectional fixtures.